# How to remove # from Wordpress One Page

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I want to remove # from the Url when clicking for example at `<a href="#contact" style="padding-bottom: 33px; padding-top: 5px;">Contact</a>`.

By default I get `example.com/#contact` but I want to get just `example.com` without the `#` in the url when clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via jquery?

something like this?

```
$("a#linkTo").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Another option would be to add a custom class to each section you link to, then use jquery/js to scroll to that.

As far as I know its better to keep the # in the url for SEO?

sample from : [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it didn't worked for me and I don't know if it's better for SEO. I just wanted to have when clicking on the link it scrolls to the anchor point without changing the url like they did on this site https://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 function clsl(){
    var c = document.getElementById("aaa").href;
    var d = c.replace(/[#]/gi, '/')
    window.location.href=d;
 }
</script>
```

Link:

```
<a href="#contact" id="aaa" style="padding-bottom: 33px; padding-top: 5px;" onClick="clsl()">Contact</a>
```

First get link and then replace `hash #` with `/` using replace function and then redirect.

Comment: thanks for the anwser but now I get an url like "example.com/contact" instead of just example.com I don't want the url to update when using the scroll to #anchor-id. For example like on this page: https://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/